# Is it possible to send different data to HDMI ports of laptop?

Tags: laptop, hdmi, windows-media-player

I want to connect two monitors to my laptop through HDMI ports. Is it possible to send different data on HDMI ports? For instance, I want to show a movie player on one screen and desktop on another screen. Is there any way of doing that

Comment: do you have two HDMI-ports?

Comment: Yup. Sorry, Its computer, not the laptop.

Comment: then, without knowing any further details about your configuration, I'd *generally* go with **yes** - the specs of your GPU wil tell you, though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that, once you have setup your two monitors following the steps below.

1) Right click on your desktop and select Display Settings from the menu.

2) On the Display Settings screen, choose Extend option underneath the multiple displays option

You will then be allowed to choose which app you want to place on which screen.